# checking if string contains a character

Tags: perl, string-comparison

I am trying to perform a simple check to see if a string contains a "%" but whenever I execute my code it will evaluate the if statement as false no matter what is in the string. My code looks like this:

```
if ($end_time =~ m{%%}) {
    ($percentage) = $end_time =~ m/=([^%%]*)%%/g;
    $percentage = sprintf("%s%%", $percentage);
    $end_time = "";
}
elsif ($duration =~ m/(overdue)/) {
    $percentage = "$end_time $duration";
    $end_time = "";
}
else {
    $percentage = "100%";
}
```

and the expected values of $end_time, substitute whatever numeric values you like.

```
"5%" or "==30%" or "+3m:26s overdue" or "13:48:40"
```

So if $end_time contains "overdue" or a "%" percentage will be 100% and $end_time will be whatever was in there before the check. And I do understand why I'm getting the results I'm getting, just not the reason my if statements are always evaluating as false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals and regex literals escape with `\`, not by doubling, and `%` does not need to be escaped in either.

```
if ($end_time =~ m{%}) {
    ($percentage) = $end_time =~ m/=([^%]*)%/g;
    $percentage = sprintf("%s%%", $percentage);
    $end_time = "";
```

`sprintf` takes a string with doubled `%` to indicate `%`, but that's not related to building strings and regex patterns.

Comment: thanks for the calirfication everything works the way I was wanting it to with those minor adjustments.

Comment: If you can recommend `index( $end_time, '%' ) > -1`, there's a +1 in it.

Comment: @Axeman, Why? `/%/` is much clearer. They both use the same algorithm to locate the string, so the only performance difference is the startup time of the regex engine, and that enters the realm of micro-optimisations. And it's already been suggested by someone else.

Comment: @ikegami: I hardly think ~40% is a micro-optimization--especially since "search this string for exact character x" is *exactly* what `index` does. Here is a benchmark of 10M trials: `regex  7189073/s    --  -30%
index 10330579/s   44%    --
`

Comment: @Axeman, Your own numbers contradict you. You said I'd only save 42 microseconds. (What an awful benchmark, btw! How can you only get one pair of numbers when benchmarking looking for something?)

Comment: @ikegami: What?? Unless you plan to eschew `index` in your code for regexes, using `index` when you want to find out if a character is in a string fits the task exactly, that it executes 44% faster is just another reason to prefer the simpler idiom. Using a regex is *needlessly* slower. If looking for an *exact* string with `index` can be said to be 'micro-optimizing` one place, then how would you ever justify using index *anywhere*?

Comment: @Axeman, I disagree about the needlessness of clarity. Furthermore, your argument that `index`'s existence implies some justification for its use is fallacious. However, I would personally justify using it when I need the position at which the pattern was found. That can be done using the match operator and `@-`, but using those is not as clear as using `index`.

Comment: @ikegami: I disagree that you're adding any clarity by not using `index`. I agree about `@-`, which is why (for clarity), I use `@LAST_MATCH_START`. I don't consider `$LAST_MATCH_START[0]` isomorphic to `index`, because if I didn't use `index`, it's not an exact match--and thus I can't use index to get either existence or location.

Comment: @Axeman, Given that all ops in question are simple, 5 ops is more complicated than 3. The match op also avoids magic numbers. But I have no problems with you disagreeing about that. I find everything else very problematic.

Comment: @Axeman, in the event of a match, `$-[0]` is indeed the same as as the return value of `index`. They both indicate the position at which the match started. Your argument that `index` and the match op are different makes `$-[0]` and the return value of `index` different is fallacious.

Comment: @ikegami: It's *not* fallacious, because I'm referring to *practice* here: *I* use `index` for exact matches, and if I needed a pattern search then `index` not going to work for positioning without 1) capturing the match, 2) using `$&`, or 3) using `@-` in addition.

Comment: @Axeman, This new argument that your use of `index` and the match op are different makes `$-[0]` and the return value of index different is *also* fallacious. None of what you are showing shows any difference whatsoever between the return value of `index` and `$-[0]` (in practice or otherwise), so you are jumping to the conclusion they they are different.

Comment: @Axeman, Anyway, I see no reason to add an alternative -- one that has no practical advantage and one I found more complicated -- to my post, especially since it's already been posted by someone else.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check if "%" is inside your string using string functions such as `index()`